# Cannot GET /api/products/1

Tags: node.js, express

I'm running a simple backend server to select a single product from my products.json database. However, it keeps sending me this message: Cannot GET /api/products/1

Here is my server.js code:

```
const express = require('express');
const products = require('./data/products')

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('API is running...');
});
app.get('/api/products', (req, res) => {
    res.json(products);
});
app.get('/api/products:id', (req, res) => {
    const product = products.find((p) => p._id === req.params.id);
    res.json(product);
});

app.listen(5000, console.log('Server running on port 5000'));
```

Comment: **Just a typo**. You're missing a `/` before the route parameter... `app.get('/api/products/:id', ...`. See https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
app.get('/api/products/:id', (req, res) => {
    const product = products.find((p) => p._id === req.params.id);
    res.json(product);
});
```

You were missing a "/" between **products** and **:id**